# Need to remove array in JSON object

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

My json object is: `{"values": {"empid": 20000, "empName": "Sourav", "empSal": 8200}}`
But I want to remove `"Values: "`. How can I do this? I have written a code in Python.
In the background It is taking the streaming data from MySQL and sending to Kinesis.

```
def main():
  connection = {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": int(sys.argv[1]),
    "user": str(sys.argv[2]),
    "passwd": str(sys.argv[3])}
  kinesis = boto3.client("kinesis",region_name='ap-south-1')
  stream = BinLogStreamReader(
            connection_settings=connection,
            only_events=[DeleteRowsEvent, WriteRowsEvent, UpdateRowsEvent],
            server_id=100,
            blocking=True,
            log_file='mysql-bin.000003',
            resume_stream=True,
        )
  for binlogevent in stream:
    for row in binlogevent.rows:
      print (json.dumps(row,cls=DateTimeEncoder)) 
      kinesis.put_record(StreamName=str(sys.argv[4]), Data=json.dumps(row,cls=DateTimeEncoder), 
                         PartitionKey="default",)
```

Comment: Delete or simply you want to call `row.values` ?

Comment: yes..I want to call only values

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that

Comment: Added  an answer with example

Comment: Can you update the question with what you really want?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Hi Sam, I want only values for json object .

Comment: Ex: {"values": {"empid": 20000, "empName": "Sourav", "empSal": 8200}} . I want to print only {"empid": 20000, "empName": "Sourav", "empSal": 8200}. Through row['values']. we can achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `row['values']` which will return the values inside of `values`.

An example in your code would be

```
kinesis.put_record(StreamName=str(sys.argv[4]), Data=json.dumps(row['values'],cls=DateTimeEncoder)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.Its working for me and sorry for wrongly interpret my question. Actually I just want only values because I want to query in Athena with this data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove `"Values: " from the string that`json.dumps` produces, you can just do a replace:

```
json_string = json.dumps(row,cls=DateTimeEncoder)
json_string = json_string.replace("Values: ", "")
```

and then use the `put_record` on that string. Your json object is a dictionary, so you can't just remove the `values:` string/key from it. If you did actually remove the `values` key, the object would be empty.